# Determine whether a list of paths contains a dynamic path

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I have a function in my firebase rules file `userRolesIncludesPermission`, this function checks a property on the user to determine whether that user has a certain permission on their role, it does so by comparing references.

This works as expected in the firebase rules file when used for security rules for firestore. Unfortunately this does not work as expected with "storage".

After research I found out that the problem is the comparison between the references from the permissions list under user.data.roles[0] and my custom made path.

Is there any better way to produce a path that can be recognizable using a list function?

Is it an unknown limitation of storage security rules?

Note that the function `getRootCollectionDocRef` works perfectly when I try to build a queryable path even in the same request (for example when I try earlier in the code to query the user)

Another note is that in the rules playground (console debugger) it works. But in an actual request from the website (dev, for now) it doesn't.

```
  function getRootCollectionDocRef(collection, docId) {
    return /databases/(default)/documents/$(collection)/$(docId);
  }


  function userRolesIncludesPermission(user, permissionId) {
    return firestore.get(user.data.roles[0]).data.permissions.hasAll([getRootCollectionDocRef("permissions", permissionId)]);
  }
```

I tried to use every available list function such as "in", "hasAny" etc.

I tried to build the path while converting it with path() function.

I tried to convert to a set.

I tried to use a hard coded non-dynamic path. It failed as long as I use a custom-made path.

However when trying to query the path with a fixed index (i.e firebase.get(permissions[1]) it worked. But this is an invalid practice. I have to make it dynamic, but the problem is that I can't loop over the list and convert the paths to strings on the fly.

Thanks in advance!!